# Shebang causes script to fail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm quite bad at bash, and I try to make a script to connect to all my switches with openSSH in order to make some configuration.

I created an array containing all my 25 switches, and then I used a loop to open SSH connection with each of them.

As I'm on Windows and using bash, I've just installed Cygwin.

However, I had to use expect and writing my password in plain text as the switches are quite poor and that is the best way for me (I won't manually put my RSA key on every single switch as it would take me as much time as writing manually the configuration on every switch).

I use the shebang #!/usr/bin/expect -f to make bash recognize expect. When I do this, the expect syntax (spawn, expect, interact) works perfectly, but my array doesn't work.

I get the following error message:

> extra characters after close-quote
>       while executing "arrayname=("172.21.21.20" "172.20.55.55" ... "

When I change the shebang, and use #!/bin/bash, expect is not found anymore :

> ./stationsnmp.sh: line 20: spawn : command not found couldn't read
>   ./stationsnmp.sh: line 24: send : command not found couldn't read
>   file "*assword*": no such file or directory ./stationsnmp.sh: line 27:
>   send : command not found ./stationsnmp.sh: line 28: interact :
>   command not found

I'm really not a pro in bash, which explains I can't get this little problem... Some help would be welcome.

EDIT : Below is a part of my code

```
#!/bin/bash

switch=("172.20.0.229" "172.20.0.232" "172.20.0.233" "172.21.0.15" "172.21.0.16" "172.21.2.1" "172.20.2.250" "172.21.3.1" "172.20.3.250" "172.21.4.1" "172.20.4.250" "172.21.6.1"  "172.20.6.250" "172.21.7.1" "172.20.7.250" "172.21.8.1" "172.20.8.250" "172.20.9.250" "172.21.9.1" "172.21.10.1" "172.20.10.250" "172.21.11.1" "172.20.11.250" "172.21.12.1" "172.21.12.250")

nmb=`echo ${#switch[@]}`

set timeout 3


for ((ii=0; ii<=$nmb; ii++))
#for ii in {0..${#switch[@]}}
do
    if [ ${switch[$ii]:5:1} -eq 1 ] 
    then
        ipdc=`echo ${switch[ii]} | grep -o -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.'`"10"


        spawn ssh admin@switch[$ii]


        expect "*assword*"
        send "PASS\r"
        interact


        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose your problem if you don't show us the code that's causing it.

Comment: Please forgive me, I added the code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `bash` and `expect`, those are two entirely different languages. You probably want to have a `bash` wrapper script with proper option handling (see `getopts`) which takes a list of IP addresses and execute your `expect` script for each IP address passed to your `bash`-wrapper. If your `expect` script is small you might want to embed it into your shell script as opposed to having it in a separate file.

EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash

switches=("172.20.0.229" "172.20.0.232")

for ip in "${switches[@]}"; do
    expect "${ip}" <<-'EOT'
        set host [lindex $argv 0]
        set timeout 3
        spawn ssh -l admin $host
        expect "*assword*"
        send "PASS\r"
        interact
        exit
EOT
done
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get everything you said. Expect is a packet I've just installed with cygwin, as I would do with an apt-get or aptitude install with a regular Linux. Now an expect.exe is in C:/cygwin/bin, like egrep, frep, etc. That is why I don't get how I should put it in my script, as expect is a .exe program. Sorry for my poor level...

Comment: Your script is run with whatever interpreter you use in the *shebang*, e.g. `#!/bin/bash` will run your script using `bash`. `bash`, however, knows nothing about `expect` syntax so you need to invoke `expect` as an external tool within your script and feed it `expect` code that it understands. You could probably implement the whole thing just using `expect` (and then have `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` as shebang) but depending on the complexity you might want a wrapper around it like you started out doing. I edited my answer to give you an idea on where to start. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why bash should about the command SSH that I have installed from the packet openssh, but not expect that I've installed from the packet expect ? If I understand what you said, using the shebang expect I should only use this command in my script ? I've never used any wrapper... Thanks again.

Comment: I think I get it : I only have to call a script in which the expect commands are located (spawn etc) with the shebang expect -f ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, I think you struggle to understand some `bash`/programming basics here and you might want to read the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). `bash` is primarily a shell that you can interact with but also a programming language. This programming language allows you to run external tools (like `ssh` or `expect`) like any other programming language. In your original question you are mixing `bash` syntax (e.g. the `for` loop which `expects` knows nothing about) and `expect` syntax (e.g. `spawn` which `bash` knows nothing about).

Comment: If what you say means what I think it does then, yes :-)

Comment: Well I'll try this then. :-) thanks and please forgive the beginner I am... :-)

Comment: And I will read the guide ! I just really want to improve myself :-)

Comment: Alright, I used my script to call another script containing the expect syntax as you said. To get the IP of the switch that is declared in the other file, I tried to make a simple $1 that works only if I don't use the shebang "expect -f". How can achieve to get the argument using this shebang ? :(